# C# - Filtering with DataView

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, dataset

I have a dataset full of order information and I am trying to filter the dataset with DataView.

This is what I have so far. This returns all the columns in the DataSet.

```
DataTable orders = dataSet.Tables[0];

EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query = from order in orders.AsEnumerable()
                                     where order.Field<Int16>("OrderID") = 2 
                                     select order;

DataView view = query.AsDataView();
```

What I want to do is that the query only return some columns not all of them. What do I do?

Answer (score 4):

Use anonymous types in your query:

```
DataTable orders = dataSet.Tables[0];

EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query = from order in orders.AsEnumerable()
                                     where order.Field<Int16>("OrderID") = 2 
                                     select new { Property1, Property2 };

DataView view = query.AsDataView();
```

Comment: You'll need `new { Property1 = order.Field<Int16>("OrderID"), ...}`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider actually using the capabilities of the `DataView` itself instead of using a sort-of roundabout LINQ solution:

```
var filter = new DataView(orders);
filter.RowFilter = "OrderID = 2";
var resultTable = filter.ToTable(false, "Column1", "Column2", "Column3");
```

The `ToTable()` method allows you to specify an arbitrary list of columns to create a new table from. Of course you can still wrap the result table in another DataView if you need to return that instead of a table:

```
var resultView = new DataView(resultTable);
```